# How do ioctls know which function to call in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

So when I call an ioctl on a device, with an ioctl number, how does it know which function to call?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `ioctl(2)` enters via the `fs/ioctl.c` function:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(ioctl, unsigned int, fd, unsigned int, cmd, unsigned long, arg)
{
    struct file *filp;
    int error = -EBADF;
    int fput_needed;

    filp = fget_light(fd, &fput_needed);
    if (!filp)
            goto out;

    error = security_file_ioctl(filp, cmd, arg);
    if (error)
            goto out_fput;

    error = do_vfs_ioctl(filp, fd, cmd, arg);
 out_fput:
    fput_light(filp, fput_needed);
 out:
    return error;
}
```

Note that there is already a filedescriptor `fd` associated. The kernel then calls `fget_light()` to look up a `filp` (roughly, file pointer, but don't confuse this with the standard IO `FILE *` file pointer). The call into `security_file_ioctl()` checks whether the loaded security module will allow the `ioctl` (whether by name, as in AppArmor and TOMOYO, or by labels, as in SMACK and SELinux), as well as whether or not the user has the correct capability (capabilities(7)) to make the call. If the call is allowed, then `do_vfs_ioctl()` is called to either handle common ioctls itself:

```
    switch (cmd) {
    case FIOCLEX:
            set_close_on_exec(fd, 1);
            break;
    /* ... */
```

If none of those common cases are correct, then the kernel calls a helper routine:

```
static long vfs_ioctl(struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd,
                  unsigned long arg)
{
    int error = -ENOTTY;

    if (!filp->f_op || !filp->f_op->unlocked_ioctl)
            goto out;

    error = filp->f_op->unlocked_ioctl(filp, cmd, arg);
    if (error == -ENOIOCTLCMD)
            error = -EINVAL;
 out:
    return error;
}
```

Drivers supply their own `.unlocked_ioctl` function pointer, like this pipe implementation in `fs/pipe.c`:

```
const struct file_operations rdwr_pipefifo_fops = {
    .llseek         = no_llseek,
    .read           = do_sync_read,
    .aio_read       = pipe_read,
    .write          = do_sync_write,
    .aio_write      = pipe_write,
    .poll           = pipe_poll,
    .unlocked_ioctl = pipe_ioctl,
    .open           = pipe_rdwr_open,
    .release        = pipe_rdwr_release,
    .fasync         = pipe_rdwr_fasync,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a map in the kernel.  You can register your own ioctl codes if you write a driver.

Edit:  I wrote an ATA over Ethernet driver once and implemented a custom ioctl for tuning the driver at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

A simplified explanation:

The file descriptor you pass to `ioctl` points to the `inode` structure that represents the device you are going to ioctl.

The `inode` structure contains the device number `dev_t i_rdev`, which is used as an index to find the device driver's `file_operations` structure. In this structure, there is a pointer to the `ioctl` function defined by the device driver.

You can read [Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Edition](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) for a more detailed explanation. It may be a bit outdated, but a good read nevertheless.